# Ant: How do I interate over all subfolders and perform a task in ant

Tags: loops, ant

Currently I do

```
<foreach list="${myfolders}" target="bundle"
     param="worksheet" inheritall="true"/>
```

to execute the target "bundle" on a list of folders. However the problem is I need to set this list. How do I use Ant to just loop through all the folders given the parent directory?

If there is a way to do this and also exclude specific folders that would be even better. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can provide a `<dirset>` for the `<foreach>` task to operate on:

```
 <foreach target="bundle" param="worksheet" inheritall="true">
      <path>
          <dirset dir="${subDir}">
               <include name="*"/>
          </dirset>
      </path>
 </foreach>
```

Notice that the `list` parameter isn't used when I do it this way.

You can't use `<dirset>` directly under the `<foreach>` as you can with `<fileset>`. However, you can put the `<dirset>` under the `<path>` as shown above. The `<include name="*"/>` prevents recursing down the directory tree.

Comment: Thank you. When I try it I get an error "The `<foreach>` type doesn't support the nested 'path' element". If I take out `<path>` then I get the error "The `<foreach>` type doesn't support the nested 'dirset' element"

Comment: What version of the antcontrib jar are you using? Try my [build.xml](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/build.xml). That's what I used for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html)

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="subant" default="subant1">

      <target name="subant1">

            <subant target="">

                 <dirset dir="." includes="*"/>
                 <target name="release" />

             </subant>

        </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

I use the [foreach](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) task from [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) for a similar job. This will call a specified target for each entry in a list, passing the entry as a parameter each time.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do this without providing a list. The set of subfolders constantly changes in my case, and I don't want to always have to update the list accordingly.

Comment: Looks like David W has already expanded on this. The "list" can actually be something that is generated automatically.